# Attaching particular layer in GL_2D_ARRAY_TEXTURE to framebuffer

Tags: opengl, textures, texture-mapping

I have a texture with target `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`. I want to render to each layer separately as FBO attachment. how do i bind particular layer to framebuffer as attachment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`glFramebufferTextureLayer` function](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glFramebufferTextureLayer) to attach the texture layer to the FBO.

```
glFramebufferTextureLayer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, someTexture, mipmapLevel, layer);
```

Alternatively, use the [`gl_Layer` variable in a geometry shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Geometry_Shader#Layered_rendering) to select at render time which layer to render to.